# Porting Site Created On Windows Apache Server to Linux Apache Server - Symlinks disappear

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, windows, migration, symbolic-link

I created a site on a testing server on my local Windows machine, and now I wish to port it to  a remote server which is Linux.  Both sites running under Apache.

To create symlinks on Windows, is stopped the server, and used `mklink /d source destination`, and I was careful to use relative syntax - eg. `..\imgdir instead of C:\htdocs\imgdir`.  I don't know if that matters, but it made sense in my brain.  Started the server, symlinks work fine.

However, when I upload the site with FTP, the symlinks are gone.  The folders just disappear.  Is this to be expected?  Is there are solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior - FTP doesn't know anything about symlinks and cannot create them - it operates on regular files and directories. Even if supported, I don't really see how it will work. Windows symlinks are different from linux symlinks.

Comment: This is what I feared.  Makes a cross platform testing server seem like a bad idea.  Here's a weird twist though:  I made up a quick test the first time I tried it.  I made a directory structure like `1/2/3/4/5`, and then in `5` created a symlink to `../../3`.  I uploaded that, and that worked:  sort of.  It created an infinitely recursive directory on Linux.

Comment: cross platform testing isn't bad idea in this case. using symlinks with web is a bad idea, most of the hosting providers won't allow web server to follow symlinks.

Comment: use .htaccess/mod_rewrite to forward requests

Comment: I think I'll just create a shell script to recreate the links.

Comment: Bad way. Use rewriting rules. Symlinks aren't available everywhere.

Comment: mod_rewrite is something I have no experience with.  If I wanted to write a mod_rewrite script to point the source of all imgs to a global image directory,how would I do that.  Also, can this be done with the css files as well? (background-images)

Comment: Yes, you can do it with anything, according to RegEx you want